# Spark Difference between local and standalone

Tags: apache-spark

If I run Spark with local[*] and then Standalone later with 2 workers (both workers are referring to the same 1 computer), is there a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standalone you are defining "containers" for the worker and spark master to run in your machine (so you can have n workers and your tasks can be distributed in the JVM of those two workers?) but in local mode you are just running everything in the same JVM in your local machine with n threads.

Comment: But what if those two workers are on the same exact machine? Is it the same as local mode then?

Comment: Both workers are separate JVM Process which internally can have multiple threads
and local will have single JVM process with 2 threads. Hence the GC and memory management will be separate for each process.  As per my experience setting up standalone cluster could be lot lead to lot of hassle hence I have shifted all my development on local[*] and for performance tests I shift to Standalone cluster.